# AES encrypt folder

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

Is it possible to encrypt a folder using AES? just like how `File.Encrypt(folderName)` would do..

All I found in the internet are examples with AES encrypting a file, not a folder..

thanks!

Comment: Can't you zip/tar/rar your forlder before encryption?

Comment: What would the result of this operation be exactly? When we encrypt a file, we get an encrypted file. When we encrypt a folder, what are we supposed to get? What is an "encrypted folder"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As folders contain a collection of files within it, i very much doubt it without converting the contents into a single file (such as a compressed archive zip/rar/7zip etc).

If you want to provide a folder name and loop through all the files encrypting it then thats one way otherwise use a zip library to zip the contents of the folder to an archive file and encrypt that (if the zip library doesn't already include AES encryption)

Comment: thanks Xander.. I got confused because in File.Encrypt(), you can encrypt a folder then when creating files inside that folder, the files created will be automatically encrypted.
I was thinking about looping through all the files inside the folder but not really recommended when it comes to performance..
maybe i'll just zip the whole folder then.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I know this one is already solved years ago. But I made a tool written in Java which utilizes the concept of MultiThreading to access files in the root folder and speed up the process of encryption and decryption.

Here is the github link https://github.com/leogitpub/OMFE

The intelligent thing about this tool is that it retains the folders and its sub structure along with the names, expect the file in the said sub folders will be encrypted to a ".enc" File extension.

It uses AES GCM 128bit cipher. Go through the readme file to learn how it works.